# How to use a window function to refer to a newer record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I believe I have a requirement to use a window function, but I am not too sure. My data is in the below format:

```
JobID   ActiveFromDate  RecID   TypeID
J1      01/12/2020      441166  LI2
J1      25/11/2020      375213  LO1
J1      24/11/2020      375207  LO2
J2      02/12/2020      441378  LO1
J2      01/12/2020      376896  LO2
J2      30/11/2020      375288  LI1
J3      03/12/2020      441894  LO2
J3      01/11/2020      374558  LI1
J3      31/10/2020      371285  LI2
J4      02/12/2020      441295  LI1
J4      13/11/2020      374598  LO2
J4      01/11/2020      374423  LO1
```

I want to get to this:

```
JobID   ActiveFromDate  ActiveToDate    RecID   TypeID
J1      01/12/2020                      441166  LI2
J1      25/11/2020      01/12/2020      375213  LO1
J1      24/11/2020      25/11/2020      375207  LO2
J2      02/12/2020                      441378  LO1
J2      01/12/2020      02/12/2020      376896  LO2
J2      30/11/2020      01/12/2020      375288  LI1
J3      03/12/2020                      441894  LO2
J3      01/11/2020      03/12/2020      374558  LI1
J3      31/10/2020      01/11/2020      371285  LI2
J4      02/12/2020                      441295  LI1
J4      13/11/2020      02/12/2020      374598  LO2
J4      01/11/2020      13/11/2020      374423  LO1
```

The AuditToDate is calculated per JobID. If there is a newer audit record for that JobID, then the AuditToDate is the AuditFromDate of the newer audit record. Otherwise it is blank.

Any ideas how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEAD` will fit here perfectly as follows:

```
SELECT JobID, ActiveFromDate,
       LEAD(ActiveFromDate) OVER (PARTITION BY JobID ORDER BY ActiveFromDate) AS ActiveToDate,
    RecID, TypeID
FROM table
```

Comment: Many thanks. I didnt even know about this function but it does the job perfectly as you said